# rails unchanged file fields got deleted on updating nested forms with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, file-upload, carrierwave, nested-forms

I've two models: **ad** and **variant**

Model: **Ad**

```
has_one :variant
accepts_nested_attributes_for :variant
```

Controller **AdsController** strong parameters:

```
params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :desc, variant_attributes: [:custom_image_1, :custom_image_2, :custom_image_3])
```

View **ads/_form.slim**

```
= f.fields_for :variant, @ad.variant || Variant.new do |va|
  - 3.times do |i|
    = va.file_field "custom_image_#{i+1}"
```

In view I added the nested form fields using a loop. The problem is when I create any **AD**, that time suppose I upload only one image in variant form (custom_image_1). Now, I came back for editing and uploaded another image on the variant (custom_image_2). 
After the update, I saw that my previously uploaded `custom_image_1` is deleted and only `custom_image_2` is present in the database.

What is the reason behind it?

I check the `params` while submitting the edit form. There only contains the `custom_image_2` in submitted attributes.

Comment: I think, if add accepts_nested_attributes_for :variant, we must add optional: true to belongs_to :ad, to make either both usage to work

Comment: @Rakesh how can you add `optional: true` in rails 4? It's a rails 5+ feature

Comment: I didn't notice the tag, I m sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope someone will find that useful:

In my strong parameters, I need to include `:id` to resolve this issue.

```
params.require(:ad).permit(:title, :desc, variant_attributes: [:id, :custom_image_1, :custom_image_2, :custom_image_3])
```